# Date filter in list-comphresion with class variable

Tags: python, list, containers

I have a list 'users' that contains objects of the class 'user'. Each user has a list 'records', which contains objects of the class 'record'. Each record has a datetime variable describing when that specific record was made.

I would like to loop over all the weeks in my data and find which users has records in that week. However, if I do something like

```
[record.datetime for user in users for record in user.records if dt < record.datetime < timedelta(days=7)]
```

I would not know which records belonged to what user, making it impossible to identify the users with records in the specific week. How do I identify the users?

My unfinished code:

```
userWeeks = list()

# Loop over each week in data
for dt in rrule.rrule(rrule.WEEKLY, dtstart=firstMonday, until=lastMonday):
    print dt

    # Find users with records in interval
    userSubset = [for user in users if user.records[...].contains()]

    # Create a UserWeek if the user has records in that week
    for user in userSubset:
        tempUserWeek = UserWeek()
        tempUserWeek.GrabInfoFromUser(user, dt, dt + timedelta(days=7))
        userWeeks.append(tempUserWeek)
```

Comment: If you want to know which *users* are relevant, why are you storing the *record's date* in the list?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment from jonrsharpe I realized that I could of course just keep the users instead of the records. By converting the list into a set, only one value for each user was kept:

```
userSubset = set([user for user in users for record in user.records if dt < record.datetime < dt + timedelta(days=7)])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want both the record and the related user, you could return a (record, user) tuple in your list comprehension:

```
[(record, user)
for user in users 
    for record in user.records 
    if dt < record.datetime < timedelta(days=7)
]
```